# How to setup an unique email address for a group of people (that is constantly evolving)?

Tags: email, user-groups, list

I work in an organization and we usually communicate through emails.
This does not work very well because our organization is very flexible:
There is new people joining and people leaving everytime.

So copy/pasting all the recipients from a previous mail when writing a new email works very bad because there is always someone missing in the email addresses or people that should not be in.

What I would like is a unique email address for the whole group.
This group address would dispatch the email to every member of the organization, and people could subscribe / leave quite easily (eg. by clicking a link or sending an email to a specific address)

I had a look at the Email Beamer function of [Mailchimp](https://mailchimp.com/features/email-beamer/), but there is a few cons with it - for example,

- When sending an email to the list, you have to reply "send" to a confirmation email (not really fast or user-friendly)
- and when people receive it, the FROM field is not the list email but its author email.
- ...

Well, I think you can now understand what I'm searching for.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: in our company we use distribution lists in outlook, and it works well. Well, people still need to be added, even subscribing to a list would take time.

Comment: distribution list. done. You haven't, however, said what email provider you use... Exchange? Gmail?

Comment: I don't want to be bound to a specific email software since we all use different ones.  I personally use Gmail...

Comment: You need an email service that can be managed from a company perspective if you want to easily add/remove people to a list. Office365 is a cloudbased form, but gmail offers similar functionality. Alternatively, an exchange server can also work, but that would probably be something you don't have, given that you mention: everyone has something else and I use gmail.

Comment: I agree with @LPChip, if you have an active directories setup then DL is the best possible method, they can be modified by the owner as well without involving the IT desk.

Comment: Hi, there is no IT desk here neither Office365 licences : we're a small non-profit association :)  There should be a free online service for this, no ?

Comment: Office365 is free for non-profits. At least several services including email are. If you’re operating like a bunch of disjointed people doing whatever they want, then you’re going to have to deal with the limitations of that culture. There is a reason why businesses have their own email system and set particular limitations on what people can and can’t do. Just saying...

Comment: I guess you're right...